# Multiple Monitor Setup with Display Port Daisy Chain

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, displayport, daisychaining, mst

I recently purchased a Lenovo Workstation fitted with an Nvidia Quadro K620 (https://www.pny.com/nvidia-quadro-k620?sku=VCQK620-PB) which supports daisy chaining monitors over the DP 1.2 / MST standard.

Now, I have 4 LG 43SM5KB displays all of which support DP 1.2.

Somehow when I daisy chain them, I can only see mirrored desktops on all 4 monitors and these are all detected as a single display on my Nvidia control panel settings and hence they all show the same output instead of showing up as separate screens. Any idea how to get this to work?

Comment: Which OS is in question?  Which Quadro driver version are you using (the latest form NVidia?)?

Comment: Win7 64bit and yes driver is updated.